# Can we redirect to totally new page in httpurlmodule without using response.redirect or server.transfer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried some work using http handler and found that we can not execute .asp files and took the httpmodule route.

I have http module on the virtual directory which is a dotnet application.Once the request comes to dotnet http module , i want to redirect to asp file which is the root folder based on some logic in .net.

I don't want to use response.redirect here, that is the main thing

root/dotnetapplication.

dotnet application has the following code.

```
 application.Context.RewritePath("http://localwww.test.com/main.asp", false);
```

This is throwing the following exception

```
'

http://locwww.test.com/main.asp' is not a valid virtual path.

[HttpException (0x80004005): 'http://locwww.allposters.com/main.asp' is not a valid virtual path.]
   System.Web.VirtualPath.Create(String virtualPath, VirtualPathOptions options) +8855691
   System.Web.HttpContext.RewritePath(String path, Boolean rebaseClientPath) +116
   ADC.Web.Code.ApcUrlRewriteModule.UrlRewriteModule_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: The exception says `main.html`, the error says `main.asp`. Which is it? Shouldn't it be `main.aspx`?

Comment: @oded , sorry that was i mistake it should be a .asp file , its main.asp ,

Comment: @oded , i want to rewrite to a different file all together which is in root folder.

Comment: what is wrong with `response.redirect` and `server.transfer`?

Comment: @Jeff as it a 301 redirect , we are not supposed to use that route? do you know any other way or can you explain me why we cannot achive this one...i really appreciate that.

Comment: response.redirect is a 302 redirect. server transfer is invisible to the client because .NET transfer the execution of the request to a different handler. im a little confused by your comment. can you explain why you cannot use `response.redirect` nor `server.transfer`?

Comment: @jeff , yeah got that , but we are not supposed to use response.redirect or server.transfer.

Comment: @jeff basically we are using some helicon , which will again resolve..and goes to recursive loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ASP` is traditionally not a .NET application page unless you re-configured the `.ASP` extension.

My guess is that you do not have `.ASP` enabled and the server thinks "main.asp" is a virtual directory not a .ASP page:

[Enabling ASP Pages in IIS 6.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737992%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @rock , can you explain more why we cannot rewrite path to a asp page in the root folder, i really appreciate that.

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you can only rewrite to another virtual path, meaning /somefolder/somefile.asp or aspx or whatever.

If you want to execute the asp page from another server and just serve the content it generates, you will need to "proxy" that page. That can be a .aspx page that makes a remote request or a proxy module for asp.net. I don't know of any, but I'm guessing there is one.